# Antlr4 - How do I report semantic error from visitor

Tags: error-handling, antlr, antlr4

I've a grammar that I want to use for both Java and C++ targets. So, I can't use any semantic predicates in the grammar as it eliminates target language independence.

I've something like -

```
expr : SOME_FUNCTION '(' INT, INT ')'
```

Now I need to add a check e.g. `INT > 2`. How do I throw an error from `visitExpr()` if this condition fails? I see that lexer/parser have error listeners but not the visitor.

Answer (score 2):

Error listeners are used to report errors. By default there's a console listener, which only prints errors to the console. This happens during the parsing (syntactic) phase. By adding an own error listener you can collect the error info into an application structure for later processing.

The semantic phase where you examine the parse tree to determine logical errors comes after the syntactic phase. But still, you can use the mentioned error info structure to receive more errors while you visit the parse tree. No need to throw an exception or something like that. All you do is to collect more errors and store them directly.

Once both phases are done you can then use the error structure to visualize all the errors (red underlining in an editor, showing in an error pane, etc.).